Using RegExp as parameter for a locator
I have this function that clicks on a locator and i want to use the locator as a parameter of type string or RegExp
export async function clickRegexLocator(page: Page, locator:string|RegExp) {
    await page.locator(locator).click();
}

The locator looks something like this, where the number 4 always changes to something else and i want to use regex instead of number 4
'#react-select-4-option-0'

My problem is that the function as it is written will display an error saying:
Argument of type 'string | RegExp' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'RegExp' is not assignable to type 'string'

What solution is there for me to use regex in this case, in order to go from this
clickRegexLocator(page, '#react-select-4-option-0');

to this ?
clickRegexLocator(page, /#react-select-/\d+-option-0/);


Regex on Ids is not supported yet, you can upvote this feature request.
You could use a prefix CSS attribute matcher, like
locator("[id^=react-select-]") but I would definitely try to find a better way to find that element.

that would be a great workaround solution but the element cannot be located using "id" like in your code. It only works with the line await page.locator('#react-select-4-option-0').click(); Based on my only line that has worked so far, how can i use it to click the locator only by the first part of the locator, something like await page.locator('#react-select-').click(); , which will not find the locator

based on your answer, i was able to formulate await page.locator("[id^=react-select-][id$=option-0]").click(); which is what i needed. Thanks!
